# Celery-beat doesnt work with daily schedule

Tags: django, redis, celery, celerybeat

I trying to run tasks with celery-beat. When I launch it by minute or hour schedule, tasks will start correctly, but if I trying to run daily task, it display in django admin panel, but not run in time.

It must to work in the following way: regular django code starts a 'start_primaries' task in Party class:

```
def setup_task(self):
    schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=7, period=IntervalSchedule.DAYS)
    self.task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
        name=self.title + ', id ' + str(self.pk),
        task='start_primaries',
        interval=schedule,
        args=json.dumps([self.id]),
        start_time=timezone.now()
    )
    self.save()
```

Is it possible that there are some settings that limit the duration of the task's life? At the moment I have the following among the Django settings:

```
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 950400
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 950400}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally,I found the anwser in github.

First, You should set 'last_run_at' to start_time - interval, so that beat will check when it was last "executed", so the next time it executes will be at start_time.

Second, update your start_time setting, and let the scheduler get the updated info.

Good luck.

https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/259

Comment: why is there no official document saying this?  Is this a temporary workaround that will be changed later? because purpose of the field last_run_at looks like the last time task is run but in this solution we are setting it even though task was never run